# HTML: Options other than 'input type=text' and 'textarea'?

Tags: html, text, input

I've seen many uses of rich-text or at least natural-looking text editing being made available with seemingly any of a page's text-containing elements.  What are my options to have this for myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be referring to the `contenteditable` attribute in HTML5. This attribute allows any arbitrary HTML element to literally become editable. It has a fairly wide support, mainly because before its appearance in the HTML5 specs it is actually a proprietary Internet Explorer attribute.

The downside of this is that, like any other form element, the appearance and capabilities of this varies wildly from browser to browser, and the quality of the HTML produced is truly atrocious. Still, if you want to have a look, go ahead and hit some of these links:

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable
http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable

Comment: I think this must have been what I was seeing.  Yeah, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking some some thing like [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) ? If so check [this](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)